# Error while establishing connection to SQL Server in WPF application

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, connection-string

I have developed a WPF application that runs some tasks in the background. Whenever it wants to connect to database I get an error. Everything works fine in local test, but it fails in Server.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and

I have checked `connectionstring` and enabled TCP/IP for database, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Is database on a host or a server?

Comment: Can you at least ping the remote server from the machine where you run your application? Can you connect to that server using *Management Studio*?

Comment: Both application and database are on server -@AshkanMobayenKhiabani

Comment: check out my answer, and also make sure that applicationpool user have access to database

Answer (score 1):

If the database is on a server, make sure that you have made the rule on the firewall to allow port 1433 (default SQL server port), if it is on a host, make sure that you are using the correct port, some hosts may change the default port and use another one like 1533.

To make sure that everything is correct try to check it with Sql Management Studio.

Comment: setting rule on port 1433 didn't help